# How to show all affected paths with git diff command?

Tags: git

When having a file (`project/olddir/file`) moved and a file (`some/file/deleted`) deleted in a Git repository, this `git diff` command shows the original location and the new location as well as the deleted file:

```
$ git --no-pager diff --diff-filter="DR" --find-renames --name-status HEAD
R100 project/olddir/file    project/newdir/file
D    some/file/deleted
```

I am only interested in all affected paths, not the status, but `--name-only` option doesn't show the original location, so I have to use the `--name-status`.

---

Can Git show me the affected paths so that it's easy to process them later, e.g.

```
project/olddir/file
project/newdir/file
some/file/deleted
```

or I am stuck with

```
$ git --no-pager diff --diff-filter="DR" --find-renames \
  --name-status HEAD | awk '{$1=""; print $0}' | xargs
project/olddir/file project/newdir/file some/file/deleted
```

Comment: For the `awk` part, try `awk '{print $2; if($3) print $3}'`. However, it does not work if there is any space in the path. In the output of `git diff`, the separator could be a NUL or a TAB instead of a SPACE, but I'm not sure.